# Apple Preview: Display Two Pages Side by Side, Starting with Odd or Even Pages

Tags: preview

I'm trying to view a PDF file in Apple Preview with two pages displayed side by side. However, I want to start with either odd or even pages, and the default settings don't seem to allow me to choose this.

I've tried going to the "View" menu and selecting "Two Pages," but I can't find an option to specify whether I want to start with odd or even pages.

Is there a way to configure Apple Preview to display two pages side by side, starting with either odd or even pages? If so, could someone please guide me through the steps or provide a workaround?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You could add a single title page to PDFs that you want to display like this.

Answer (score 1):

Preview displays the pages as if it were a book.  This is by design. Apple has not changed this in spite of users asking for the flexibility you want.

You should explore other apps. Some behave like Preview, some behave with pages 1 & 2 at the start (no choice) and some give you the choice.

Apps that are known to give a choice of two-page views:

- [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/acrobat/kb/install-reader-dc-mac-os.html) in **View > Page Display > Show Cover Page** menu toggle.
- [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/) in **View > Page Display > Separate Cover Page** menu toggle.
- [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) in **PDF > PDF Display > Book mode** menu toggle.

Right now I don't know of others!

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for edits as well as addition.

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit carried away... ;-)

Comment: Not at all. Foxit Reader is likely the best solution as it avoids the heavyweight install from Adobe.